# Android HostApduService should it run always?

Tags: android, android-service, nfc, android-things, android-tap-and-pay

In my application, I have my own **HostApduService** for receive command APDU from NFC device. When my testing phone restart or when I change the default service to my app from Android settings UI, I saw my **HostApduService** getting created.

If I do tap to NFC device, it will continue the process and complete. At the end it will not destroy my **HostApduService**.

According to this observation, I think my **HostApduService** should always running in the device, if my application is the default service for this.

1. Is my above assumption correct?
2. If yes, Do we have cases this service can destroy? When it can destroy?

Thank you in advance...